# Posso usar um SELECT dentro do IF?

Tags: php, mysql, select, if

Me ocorreu de tentar fazer essa ação, mas, parece que dá erro. É possível?

```
//EVITANDO DUPLICIDADE
if ($legenda > "0") {
    SELECT legenda FROM aula_upload_arquivo WHERE legenda = $legenda;
    echo 'Existe esse arquivo';
} else {
    echo 'Não existe o arquivo';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode, mas não desta forma. Para que use o SQL você deve usar alguma função para isso, como por exemplo o `mysqli_query` ou equivalente.

Dessa forma, seria como fazer:

```
if ($legenda > 0) {
   $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT legenda FROM aula_upload_arquivo WHERE legenda = '$legenda'");
   // ...
} else {
   // ...
}
```

Não há nada de errado em fazer executar uma query dentro de um `if`. Se já é isso que esta fazendo, então mencione qual o erro exato que ocorre.

Answer (score 0):

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE dado='$dado'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
echo "Este Dado já existe";
exit();
} else {
 if(mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO table (dado) VALUES ('$dado')");
 echo "Dados inseridos com sucesso";
}
```

Comment: Oi, Leandro. Desculpa, eu esqueci de mencionar. Eu uso o sistema de PDO. Não consegui encaixar a sua resposta para testar. E eu não sei como transformar de msqli para pdo. :-(

Comment: Bacco, why do not you take advantage of it and answer the question? An IF loop was made with an MSQLI response and accurate in PDO. Another question, about CLASSES, IF, INSERT and also no answer. Why not help, instead of hinder?

Comment: @bacco, read this not please

Comment: @Tátto a resposta do **Inkeliz** não funciona como desejado? É o mesmo com *PDO*.

Comment: @NoobSaibot, obrigado por me ajudar. Não deu certo. Porque como todo o meu sistema é em PDO, quando eu coloquei a aplicação com msqli acabou dando conflito, porque tem a CLASSE do sistema de UPLOAD que trava muitas ações que são feitas dentro do código.

Comment: NoobSaibot, eu segui o que o @bacco disse e mudei o sistema para o campo: "identifica" como UNIQUE. Ficou show, realmente não tem mais como duplicar, mas, me gerou outro problema, pois, como tem a CLASSE em Upload, aparecem alguns erros. Vou colocá-los no próximo comentário.

Comment: Na primeira inserção do campo "identifica", beleza, cadastra normalmente, mas, na segunda vem esse erro, aliás, esses erros:

Comment: Não consigo postar os erros aqui...

Comment: Como inserir os erros aqui?

Comment: Você pode [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/347888/edit) a pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEMA RESOLVIDO:

01) Não foi necessário fazer essa ação com SELECT dentro do IF. 
02) Bem mais fácil, foi transformar um dos campos em UNIQUE
03) Para que sempre o dado seja exclusivo, foi inserida a informação no campo, usando o nome do usuário e sua ID, junto com um substantivo qualquer.